# Windows Forms Application Standalone database

Tags: c#, winforms

I am planning to create a windows forms application with standalone database.
When i tried to add a new database item in Visual Studio i can see a Dataset and Service-based Database. Could you please let me know which one should i use or is there any other db i can use.

Comment: Think of a dataset as the results from a query.  As far as databases you can use, that's very broad subject.  Have you ever worked with a database before?  If so, do you know if you are looking at relational or non-relational(ie document db's)?  Further, size is a big issue, do you plan on storing a few records, or terabytes worth?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlite.net:

https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

It is pretty straight forward to use. You need to add the appropriate DLLs to your project.

Comment: Since this is a .NET project I would add it with NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite